# Spring @PropertySource value not overridding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

In my sprint boot application, I have a configuration class  to read property files: `common.properties` and `dev.properties`. I have the same key `server.url` in both the property files. The value is not overridden. As per the spring documentation, the last property file value should be taken. But it's not working. I am using the spring annoatation `@PropertySource` to read values.

**ServerConfiguration class**

```
@Component
@PropertySources(
{
    @PropertySource(value = "file:Common/config/common.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:Dev/config/dev.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public final class ServerConfiguration {


private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

/**
 * The Server URL
 */
@Value("${server.url}")
private String serverUrl;

}
```

**common.properties**

```
server.url=ws://some ip
```

**dev.properties**

```
server.url=ws://localhost:8080
```

The value from `common.properties` is taken always. I tried changing the order, but still it's not working.

Comment: that isn't a configuration it is a component. Use `@Configuration` instead of what you have now. Also why are you trying to roll your own? Just use the spring boot support that already provides loading different files for different environments.

Comment: I need this class as a bean only.

Comment: Then move your `@propertysource` somewhere else and don't call it configuration if it isn't configuration. Also `@Configuration` classes are also beans...

Comment: If I annotate this class as `@Configuration`, what other modifications should I make in this class ?

Comment: Well about none.. Unless you are doing more with this class then you are showing here.

Comment: But my question is why the value from `dev.properties` is not taken ?

Comment: Because, as I stated, @PropertySource on a non `@Configuraiton` is pretty useless. Next to that each property source is executed in order. As soon as the property is resolved it isn't tried again. Just put all your files in a single `@PropertySource` the `value` property takes a comma seperated list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127807/discussion-between-krishnanunni-p-v-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @Deinum Not working as you suggested. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

you need to add in the application.properties file your active profile

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```